# MaterialUI AutoComplete - cannot get the onChange event to fire

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui, react-testing-library

I have this MaterialUI Autocomplete component:

```
import React, {useContext, useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import Autocomplete, { createFilterOptions } from '@mui/material/Autocomplete';
import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField';
import { FINN_HUB_STOCKS_URL } from '../../consts';
import './stock-picker.css';
import {TimeSeriesChartContext} from '../../time-series';

const filterStockOptions = createFilterOptions({
    limit: 100,
    matchFrom: 'any',
    stringify: (option) => `(${option.displaySymbol}) ${option.description}`,
});

const StockPicker = () => {
    const [ stockListOpen, setStockListOpen ] = useState(false);
    const [ stocksList, setStocksList ] = useState([]);
    const [ stocksListInputValue, setStocksListInputValue ] = useState('');
    const [ selectedStocks, setSelectedStocks] = useState([]);
    const { dispatch } = useContext(TimeSeriesChartContext);

    const handleStockInputChange = (event, value) => {
        console.log('STOCKINPUTCHANGE', value);
        setStocksListInputValue(value);
        if (!value) {
            setStockListOpen(false);
        }
    };

    const handleStockChange = (event, value) => {
        console.log('STOCKCHANGE', value);
        if (value.length <= 3) {
            setSelectedStocks(value);
            dispatch({ type: 'UPDATE_STOCKS', payload: value });
        }
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        axios({
            method: 'get',
            url: FINN_HUB_STOCKS_URL,
        }).then((response) => {
            setStocksList(response.data);
        });
    }, []);

    return (
            <Autocomplete
                className="stock-picker"
                clearOnBlur={false}
                data-testid="stock-picker"
                filterOptions={filterStockOptions}
                filterSelectedOptions
                forcePopupIcon={false}
                getOptionLabel={(option) => `(${option.displaySymbol}) ${option.description}`}
                id="stocks-list"
                inputValue={stocksListInputValue}
                loading
                multiple
                onChange={handleStockChange}
                onClose={() => setStockListOpen(false)}
                onInputChange={handleStockInputChange}
                onOpen={() => {
                    if (stocksListInputValue) {
                        setStockListOpen(true);
                    }
                }}
                open={stockListOpen}
                options={stocksList}
                renderInput={(params) => (
                    <TextField
                        {...params}
                        data-testid="stock-picker-input"
                        variant="outlined"
                        label="US Stock Symbols"
                    />
                )}
                value={selectedStocks}
            />
    );
}

export default StockPicker;
```

...and this test...

```
test('Then the stock is set', () => {
    render(<StockPicker />);
    const autoComplete = screen.getByTestId('stock-picker');
    const input = within(autoComplete).getByTestId('stock-picker-input').querySelector('input');
    autoComplete.focus();
    fireEvent.change(input, { target: { value: 'ASCOT RESOURCES LTD' } });
    fireEvent.keyDown(autoComplete, { key: 'ArrowDown' });
    fireEvent.keyDown(autoComplete, { key: 'Enter' });

    ...
});
```

The `handleStockInputChange` method get called, but the `handleStockChange` method does not.

Comment: Did you tried `onChange={(e,v) => handleStockChange(e, v)}` ?

Comment: Yeah, it's the same.